# DJS - Edit the embed when someone reacts with specific emoji

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

What I'm trying to do is to change the color of an embed when someone adds a reaction.
The struggle I'm currently facing is making it the *if* statement fire. So haven't gotten very far.

I'm also probably not targeting any specific embed. As the embed (*suggestionsEmbed*) has been sent multiple times.

EDIT: Updated with current code. This is working except for one thing. No embed other than the last sent can be edited. See what I mean [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvXlC.png).

```
   // SUGGESTIONS EMBED - BEGINS
var suggestionsEmbed;
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.channel.id === channelSuggestions && !message.author.bot) {
    db.add('counterP.plus', 1);
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#f9db73')
    .setTitle(`Suggestion #${await db.fetch('counterP.plus') + await db.fetch('counterM.minus')}`)
    .setDescription(message.content)
    .setAuthor({ name: message.author.username, iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: message.author.id });
    suggestionsEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
    suggestionsEmbed.react('')
    suggestionsEmbed.react('');
        message.delete({ timeout: 0 });
        console.log(db.fetch('counterP.plus'));
}
})
// SUGGESTIONS EMBED - ENDS

// CHANGE EMBED COLOR - BEGINS
const suggestionsApproved = '';
const suggestionsDenied = '';
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelSuggestions) {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === suggestionsApproved && reaction.message.id === suggestionsEmbed.id) {
        const suggestionsEmbedApproved = new MessageEmbed(suggestionsEmbed.embeds[0]).setColor('#76de51')
            suggestionsEmbed.edit({ embeds: [suggestionsEmbedApproved] });
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the introduction of `discord.js` v13, you need intents declared in your bot. They were introduced so that developers could choose which types of events their bot wanted to receive. You can learn more about Intents here => [Gateway Intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents). First, you have to add the `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent in your client by using:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    ]
})
```

Then after that, you can just use your original code to do whatever you want. Although you might get an error saying `DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body embeds[0].description: This field is required`, so to fix that, all you have to do is add the `.setDescription()` to your edited embed and then send it. Your final code might look something like this:

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
    ]
})
const suggestionsApproved = '';
const suggestionsDenied = '';
const channelSuggestions = 'your channel id'
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelSuggestions) { // Check if the reaction was in a particular channel
        if (reaction.emoji.name === suggestionsApproved) { // Check which emoji was selected
            const suggestionsEmbedApproved = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('your color')
                .setDescription('your description');
            suggestionsEmbed.edit({ embeds: [suggestionsEmbedApproved]});
        }
    }
})
```

**Edit**

In response to the new question, here is the answer:
Instead of naming the embed as `suggestionsEmbed`, the correct way to do it would be to first create an embed with a different name and then use `const suggestionsEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embedName] })` so that the code will be like:

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('title')
    .setDescription('description')
    .setColor('color')
const suggestionsEmbed = await message.channel.send({
    embeds: [embed]
})
```

**Second Edit**

Since you are already using `await message.channel.send()`, you don't have to use `.then()`. All you have to do is change this:

```js
const suggestionsEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }).then(sentEmbed => {
    sentEmbed.react("")
    sentEmbed.react("")
});
```

to this:

```js
const suggestionsEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
suggestionsEmbed.react('')
suggestionsEmbed.react('')
```

**Editing the Embed**:

Use:

```js
const suggestionsEmbedApproved = new MessageEmbed(suggestionsEmbed.embeds[0]).setTitle('asdfasdf')
suggestionsEmbed.edit({ embeds: [suggestionsEmbedApproved] });
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting closer! Getting this error:
/Users/User/Desktop/discord/bot/main.js:90
        suggestionsEmbed.edit({ embeds: [suggestionsEmbedApproved]});
                                         ^
TypeError: suggestionsEmbed.edit is not a function

Comment: What have you defined `suggestionsEmbed as`? Is it like `const suggestionsEmbed = await message.channel.send()`?

Comment: All you have to do is `const suggestionsEmbed = await message.channel.send({embed: [embed]})`

Comment: Thanks for the immediate replies. Will try it! I've pasted my code in my post above.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. But I’m not getting this to work.

Comment: What's the error? No error is idiotic here!

Comment: suggestionsEmbed.edit({ embeds: [suggestionsEmbedApproved]});           
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'edit')

Comment: Can you edit your questions with your current code?

Comment: There you go! :)

Comment: For that you can use the official discord.js guide on embeds. I'm writing  the answer in my answer

Comment: This almost worked. It does edit everything in the embed, and I want to keep everything and only edit the color. It also changes the last message regardless of what message I react to. The channel will contain more than one message, and it needs to work on each message separately. You're being such a great help, thank you.

Comment: You can just wrap the part of the code where you change the embed details in an if statement where you check: `if (reaction.message.id === suggestionsEmbed.id)`

Comment: You can do that to check if the message a person reacted to was the message which contained the embed which you sent

Comment: This is almost working as I intend it to. Don't know if I should make a new post about my current issue. However I've updated my post with my current code and the only issue left - which is that I can't change earlier sent embeds, only the last one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Each time someone writes in this channel. I retrive that message and put it in an embed. So the embed variable is sent over and over again. When I react on an embed that has been sent earlier it doesn’t edit that embed. The current code can only affect the last sent embed

Comment: I've added the answer

Comment: Thanks Caladan! It works as intended. I just had to change the if condition, but was easy even for me! I'm gonna call this post finished. The only thing left is that the bot crashed if I react to messages sent before the bot was initiated. I will see if I can find the solution, so I don't take up too much of your time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So your code is trying to edit the embed rather than the message that the embed is in, (weird I know) but this should work for you.

Discord intents may vary based on your coding but should look similiar

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS],
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
})
```

It should be able to pick up those reactions with the below.

```js
const suggestionsApproved = 'insertReactionEmojiName'
const suggestionsDenied = 'insertReactionEmojiName'
const channelSuggestions = 'yaddayadda'

// I would use a different emoji, one that you can get an name from like this
//  which in discord is named :thumbsup:


client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.partial) {
        // If the message this reaction belongs to was removed, the fetching might result in an API error which should be handled
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message:', error);
            // Return as `reaction.message.author` may be undefined/null
            return;
        }
    }   

    const targetMessage = reaction.message
    const channel = targetMessage.channel

    if (channel.id === channelSuggestions) {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === suggestionsApproved) {
            const suggestionsEmbedApproved = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#1dce1d')
            
            targetMessage.edit({
                embeds: [suggestionsEmbedApproved]
            })
            console.log('fired!')
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Not getting it to work. The console.log wont trigger, so I'm not getting into the if statement at all. EDIT: Added a console.log() beneath client.on. It's not triggering.

Comment: I updated my answer, please make sure that you have partials added and let me know if that works now

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but not getting it to work. Getting *ReferenceError: message is not defined* - **(const channel = message.channel)** and *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')* - **if (channel.id === channelSuggestions) {**

Comment: You can just change `const channel = message.channel` to `const channel = reaction.message.channel`

Comment: Fixed my code as well. I changed what message was defined as. `const channel = message.channel` should be `const channel = targetMessage.channel`

Answer (score 0):

To edit any embed which was reacted to instead of only the previous sent one, you can use:

```js
const suggestionsEmbedApproved = new MessageEmbed(reaction.message.embeds[0]).setColor("Your color")
reaction.message.edit({ embeds: [suggestionsEmbedApproved] });
```